# AWS S3 download only txt files without folders?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have configured AWS CLI, everything connected and works.

Please guide me how can I download files only for example .txt files or .anyformat files but without the folders?

My command brings me all the bucket with folders:

aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket ~/My_Files/ --recursive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command alone.

You could either download the files into directories with the AWS CLI and then write a shell command to move them, or you could write a small script (eg in Python) that downloads the files and saves them where you wish (as an alternative to using the AWS CLI).

If you use the AWS CLI, it will always recreate the folder structure.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Hey, I checked this command on my S3 bucket and it seems to work. Let me try to explain and that might help you:

`aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/ /home/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"`

first we put the bucket name then after / we specify the location on our system where it should be copied to. If you are on a Windows you can use C:/Users/... or just /home/ in Ubuntuand the rest of the command is straight forward. Recursive so the shell won't stop on 1 file and usage of exclude and include means all files are ignored unless they are .txt
One thing to notice you might not have a right to copy to a directory or you are in root directory, check if you are pointing to a valid directory where the files from bucket are going to get copied or just navigate to it and use the dot after pointing the s3 bucket name.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html

Comment: can you please try again, I did not put the * inside of "exclude"

Comment: Did it with and without it. Same on Ubuntu 17.1.
It brings the folders + subfolders + text files.

Comment: Here is my structure in S3 MyBucket: folder1: subfolder1: subfolder1: txt files.
I just copy paste to my terminal your command, and I completely understand your solution, what I can't understand is why it doesn't do what I want it to do.

Comment: `company@company:~$ aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ /home/company/My_Files/AWS/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"`
`company@company:~$ `

Comment: Nothing added to my folder. The command completed, but without any visible effect.

Comment: Maybe this is the key to the solution, the files are text but they don't have a .txt ending. But just names. Here is an example:
`2018-05-06-14-10-34-499`

Comment: Then it should work by using the right location structure - I tested it adding 3 subfolders below and it copied all properly to selected directory. 
``aws s3 cp s3://MyBucket/folder1/subfolder1/subfolder1/ /home/username --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.txt"

EDIT: not sure, but that might be the case. It works perfectly fine with my bucket

Comment: That is exactly what I want to avoid, given a bucket "I don't care" about the folder structure, just give me the files without folders, is it possible?

Comment: Like we do in linux, find -f to find files only.